# How to eat like normal during major renovations

Tags: home

Our entire kitchen and dining room has been removed from our house. It's gonna take 5 weeks to rebuild and in the meantime, we don't wanna blow money eating out the whole time.

We have:

```
power
fridge
bathroom sinks (hot and cold)
outdoor spigots (cold only)
a few tables and some plasticware
```

How can we cook/eat/clean in a way that makes sense for this arrangement? Family of 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To cook anything, you need a heat source. A few options immediately come to mind - either indoor electric appliances, or an outdoor grill. A hot plate is essentially a small, portable, one- or two-burner electric stove. Set it up on a spare table in another room to replicate your stove. You could also use a slow cooker or toaster oven, which are other heat sources that just require an available electric outlet. Alternatively, you could use an outdoor grill as a heat source, giving you a bit more variety in your cooking options. Each of these options are all relatively inexpensive, and would certainly be a net positive if the alternative is 5 weeks of restaurant bills.

The other major detriment of losing the kitchen is the difficulty of doing dishes. You could use disposable plates/cups/flatware to avoid doing most dishes, but you'll still need a way to clean pots/pans/kitchen utensils. Doing dishwashing in the bathroom sink or shower isn't ideal due to potential for cross-contamination with all the nasty things living there. You may be best off washing dishes outside with a hose, or using the hot tap in the bathroom to fill a bucket and doing the dishes outside - be sure to use biodegradable dish soap for camping.

Comment: A simple **microwave oven** is also inexpensive and will greatly expand your possibilities. Same for an **electric kettle** if you don't already have one (instant hot drinks, instant noodles, instant soups etc).

Comment: Less common in regular US stores, but common in Asian supermarkets are portable butane gas stoves that are suitable for indoor use. If you find a hot plate insufficient as a stove replacement, you might consider one of these.